# C# - Do something when File Download is completed

Tags: c#, .net

So, I am trying to play a Sound File when the Download is completed, but I dont work. Here my Class:

```
private String url = "http://download2098.mediafire.com/aut75nnjxh6g/34h69ha3ka375p4/Fed-Up+-+Virus+%28online-audio-converter.com%29.wav";
    private String file = @"C:\VirEDos\virus.wav";

    public Sounder()
    {
        download();
    }

    private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Cancelled)
        {
            play();
        }
    }

    private void download()
    {
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.DownloadFile(url, file);
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        }
    }

    private void play()
    {
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(file);
        player.Load();
        player.Play();
    }
```

Well, I added the Imports and All Stuff but why isnt it working?

Comment: Is play method ever being hit?

Comment: Your line `webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += ..` isn't executed until *after* the download has finished. Try and put it before you execute the download.

Comment: Nothing Changed

Comment: The [DownloadFileCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted.aspx) event fires for *asynchronous* downloads, which you don't use. Just call `play` when the download is done.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use the `WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted` event. This is only useful in asynchronous downloads. This event is not raised if you call `DownloadFile` like stated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> This event is raised each time an asynchronous file download operation
>   completes.Asynchronous file downloads are started by calling the
>   DownloadFileAsync methods.

Instead you can try this:

```
private String url = "http://download2098.mediafire.com/aut75nnjxh6g/34h69ha3ka375p4/Fed-Up+-+Virus+%28online-audio-converter.com%29.wav";
private String file = @"C:\VirEDos\virus.wav";

public Sounder()
{
    download();
    play();
}

private void download()
{
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.DownloadFile(url, file);
    }
}

private void play()
{
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(file);
    player.Load();
    player.Play();
}
```